# Retain information on textarea when reloaded in new tab/page

Tags: php, linux

From the topic itself, how am i supposed to do that?... I'm getting the output from linux to Php using pipes.

e.g

```
echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='20' readonly='readonly' style='resize:none;'>";

       $dev = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);

       echo $dev;

       echo "</textarea>";

       fclose($pipes[1]);
```

Here is my form.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="radio" name="cmd" value="./iodev scan">Scan<br />
<input type="radio" name="cmd" value="./monitor">Enable Monitoring<br />
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

Now when i got the data i need it to retain in the textarea when loaded into a new tab or page or on page reload it will sit there and not disappear.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like amusing your textarea name is `textPipes`

```
if (!isset($_POST['textPipes']) || empty($_POST['textPipes'])) {
    $_POST['textPipes'] = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
}

echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='20' readonly='readonly' style='resize:none;' name='textPipes' >";
echo $_POST['textPipes'];
echo "</textarea>";
```

*** EDIT ! ***

Based on your request you can also sore it in Memcache

```
$mem = new Memcache();
$mem->connect("localhost",11211);

#Identify current user
$currentUser = "demic0de";

#Create Unique Key
$key = $currentUser . sha1($pipes[1]);

if(!$mem->get($key))
{
    #set value and expire every 10 mins 
    $mem->set($key,stream_get_contents($pipes[1]) ,null,600);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
}


echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='20' readonly='readonly' style='resize:none;' name='textPipes' >";
echo $mem->get($key);
echo "</textarea>";
```

Comment: Tried it but still i get no output when i open it in a new page?

Comment: Can i just store the output in a file then when it reloads it looks in that file and echo it out in the textarea?.. then when i hit scan again it will delete the old textfile and get the new output?

Comment: Yes its possible to save it in a file but i think the best is to save it in a cache system like memcache ... if you have that installed and i can add the code

Comment: Yes i do have a memcached installed in my system, can you show me how can it be done? thanks

Comment: thanks so this will be faster and reliable than storing it in a text file? can i do this $dev = $mem->get($key); echo $dev;  because i'll be reading on the data for string comparison.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17526/discussion-between-demic0de-and-baba)